# Delete Item from ListBox and Update Total Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, button, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I am new in VB, I have managed to add items in the listbox and update the total as I keep on adding the items. 
My Question is
I want to delete Selected Items from ListBox and update the Total/Deduct price, but I don't know how to do it. I am posting a sample code that I used to add the total.

```
Private Sub btncoffee6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncoffee6.Click
        Dim sum As Double
        sum = 1.5
        itembox.Items.Add("Regular Coffee       $1.00")
        For x As Integer = 0 To itembox.Items.Count - 1
            sum += Val(itembox.Items.Item(x).ToString)
        Next
        txttotal.Text = sum.ToString
        itembox.Items.Add(sum)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try removeAt() and yes get some tutorial

```
Dim sum as Double
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    itembox.Items.RemoveAt(itembox.SelectedIndex)
    sum = sum - Val(itembox.Items.Item(itembox.SelectedIndex).ToString)        
    txttotal.Text = sum.ToString
    itembox.Items.Add(sum)
End Sub
```

Comment: I will. Thanks, But now after I add items in listbox. Instead of adding the total it multiplies...

Comment: @iwolverine I have updated the answer.....the last time I just showed you an example of RemoveAt()...if the problem still persists or if I have misunderstood, let me know

Comment: I have tried your method, but it gives me error, that un-handled exception